# Syntax highlighting uses "invisible" colors when using VIM in SSH from Windows 10

Tags: ssh, vim, raspberry-pi, powershell

I have gone very old school but it's is great fun. `vim` is great at editing without GUI so connecting to a remote data collecting PI it gives a very simple stack to maintain code and settings.

It works perfectly and if I

```
set t_Co=0
```

(Terminal to Monochrome) it works very well. But in normal colour mode I get some text invisible. I am using `vim-nox` as it gives syntax highlighting for python.

I can change the Windows Powershell colours to help but I cannot control the syntax highlighting colours. I am struggle at where to set the configuration. I really want to be able to control it for each separate `vim` session as the `vim` seems to behave differently on the Pi console versus the SSH from powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had issues with the terminal emulation support in Powershell. You might want to consider looking into [Putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html) for connecting to the PI. The terminal support is complete and mature.

Comment: I was hoping to simply use the Windows 10 shell. For all their might Microsoft still cannot layer an OS correctly. I will look at Putty but I would still like to find where to config the colours to be visible. I might need a script to configure it, first checking the terminal type.

Comment: Putty looks fine and is the simple solution. Thanks I will use it.

Comment: As a Geek I would still want to know how to fix the Windows SSH issue but back to play with Python now.

Comment: That would be nice, I would like to also. Unfortunately Microsoft moves at it's own pace with it's own agenda (eg: just enough support to make `git` work from a DOS window). You might be waiting quite some time for that feature to make it up the priority chain.

Comment: I had forgotten that this was still open as I am using Putty with out any issues at all. Why do Microsoft bother to do it at all if they are not going to do it right. Thank you.

Comment: I've never been a big fan of microsoft for reasons not important here. In all fairness though, Satya Nadella has gone to great lengths to bring MS under a more "compatible" umbrella. It's probably been a hard sell but need to give him some credit. For instance, being able to SSH into/out of a Windows host without buying proprietary software is noteworthy. While the terminal support *IS* somewhat janky, this could be due to the underlying software which wasn't really intended for VT or ANSI terminal support. I would expect it will improve with age but who knows. Time will tell.